# Google Docs - disable "translation" suggestions?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

This started for me suddenly today. There may be a better way to ask this question, suggestions about how to clarify the question are certainly welcome.

So, sometimes (often) when I am typing now, Google Docs will automatically convert entire sentences. Even worse, they are sometimes complete nonsense, sometimes they are identical to the words already typed (shown), sometimes just the white-space is removed. The words I type instantly become new words. When this happens, I can hover over the new wording/sentence, and then I am shown a tool-tip such as this:

[image: Why is it showing this suggestion, anyway? The suggestion is the same as the original text!]

**Does anyone know how to turn off this behavior?**

Not shown in the image are the cases where sentences with proper nouns have their verbs removed, random normal words are capitalized, and so on. Spaces seem to have a lot to with it, as those are also removed in some cases. "This is fine." auto-magically became "Thisisfine." after being typed, for example. Further, my menu sometimes renders with a space, such as "M ore" instead of "More", and this appears as a tool-tip also:

[image: Rendering issue that also triggers the sentence suggestion tool-tip]

I don't care why or what is causing this buggy behavior - I just want these "Original Text" tooltips to disappear! But I'm including as much info as I can in case it helps anyone answer my question...

Tools -> Preferences is my usual go to, but that's not one of the settings (every box is checked off now). Having "Show Spelling Suggestions" is off, closest I could think of to "Edit my sentence?" toggle, but the dialog still shows up. (Note that since then none of my sentences have been auto-replaced, if need be I'll report more info about the conditions for triggering bizarre sentence suggestions.)

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing a similar problem.  I wanted to type 'Verse 2' but translate kept replacing it with 'fresh 2'!  I could not find a way to turn if off, though I did make a suggestion to the dictionary that i just wanted my own spelling. From the research I have done there is not a way to just turn off the nonsense. But I found a way:
The workaround for me was to choose 'translate document' from the tools menu, then I selected American English, (English English is my default) which created a copy of my doc, which had my original spelling intact.

Of course, your results may likely vary.

Answer (score -2):

copy and paste your page and paste it in a new one. problem solved.